# mysqldump: Error: Index for table is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table - does this mean repair was done?

Tags: mariadb, innodb, mysqldump

I ran into the same database trouble that another user described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317572/mariadb-missing-file-checkpoint) and I managed to get mysqld started by setting `innodb_force_recovery = 6`, which allowed me to perform a backup using `mysqldump -u<username> -p -f --all-databases > all.sql`.  However, this backup resulted in a set of error messages:

```
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table <table1> is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table <table1> at row: 0
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table <table2> is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table <table2> at row: 6
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table <table3> is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table <table3> at row: 0
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table <table4> is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table <table4> at row: 0
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table <table5> is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table <table5> at row: 0
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table <table6> is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table <table6> at row: 0
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table <table7> is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table <table7> at row: 0
```

Does the "try to repair it" mean that `mysqldump` did, in fact, try to repair it (and succeeded), or does it mean that I should try to repair it as a next action, and if so, what commands do I need to issue now?  Do I need to re-run `mysqldump`?

10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

I just did `SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;` to get a list, and the list shows different engines (Aria, Memory, InnoDB, MyISAM) for different tables, but with regard to the tables 1-7 referenced above, they are all InnoDB.

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` ( `config_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `config_value` mediumtext NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`config_name`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin |

They do not have the same schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I should try to repair it as a next action" <- this one. `mysqldump`/`mariadb-dump` doesn't attempt to repair anything, it maintains focused on dumping.

There are `ER_NOT_KEYFILE` errors generated in InnoDB under some conditions so its not an exclusive Aria/MyISAM error.

"REPAIR TABLE" isn't implemented on InnoDB, try dropping the indexes on these tables and re-creating the indexes.

Consider adding --routines/ triggers to your mysqldump. It might be worth trying to use this dump as a restore mechanism, but copy (when shutdown) the current datadir first.